# sparql regex file extension

Tags: regex, xpath, sparql

I'm trying to develop a SPARQL Query to capture the file extension in an object of a RDF.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
*
WHERE { 
    ?s <http://URI/identifier> ?o .
    BIND(REPLACE(?o,".*\.(\w+)", "$1") AS ?filetype)
} LIMIT 10
```

My Regular Expression `(.*\.(\w+)` is getting an error though.

```
MALFORMED QUERY: Lexical error at line 5, column 25.  Encountered: "." (46), after : "\".*\\"
```

However my expression works in my [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/DnRy2Z/1)

What characters do I need to escape and how?

Comment: Your `REPLACE` is missing an argument. You're not saying what the pattern match should be replaced _by_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message I am guessing you are using RDF4J Console or Workbench. There is an open issue with the escaping of special characters for SPARQL regexes in these tools. See https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j-tools/issues/72 .

There is a workaround, which is to not just double up on backslashes, like Tim suggested in his answer, but to use 4 backslashes for each special character. You'll also need to add a third argument to your `REPLACE` to make it legal (presumably you want to keep only the extension):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
*
WHERE { 
    ?s <http://URI/identifier> ?o .
    BIND(REPLACE(?o,".*\\\\.(\\\\w+)", "$1") AS ?filetype)
} LIMIT 10
```

Admittedly ugly. A fix is being worked on.